# Accessing the elements of a matrix in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame which is the output obtained after using aggregate function,

```
 >df
  Type     mean        sd
1 A        76.088250   3.233297
2 B        78.403967   4.144146
3 C        102.855533  44.775766
```

The second and the third columns are stored as a matrix.
For example,

```
>df[2] 
  mean        sd
1 76.088250   3.233297
2 78.403967   4.144146
3 102.855533  44.775766
```

I want to merge the first and second column of df[2] with a symbol in between, i.e. the desired output is

```
  mean ± sd
1 76.088250 ± 3.233297
2 78.403967 ± 4.144146
3 102.855533 ± 44.775766
```

To do this, I want to access the first column and the second column of df[2]. Probably a very simple question, but I am not able to find a way to do this.
I tried the following,

```
Matrix <- df[2]
print(Matrix[,1])
```

The output is

```
          mean        sd
[1,]  76.08825  3.233297
[2,]  78.40397  4.144146
[3,] 102.85553 44.775766
```

Expected output,

```
    mean
1  76.08825 
2  78.40397
3 102.85553
```

I would like to ask for help. Excuse me for the naive question, I'm a beginner in R.

Comment: Probably best to unpack that second column with `df <- cbind(df[1], df[[2]])`, or fix it upstream. Note you need `[[` to get the matrix by itself, not a data frame of a matrix. (You can also use that approach for subsetting directly, e.g. `df[[2]][ , 1, drop = FALSE]`.) After unpacking, everything will work more normally.

Comment: @RonakShah Thank you for posting. I could obtain only "±" in the output though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the matrix and not the dataframe.. ie `df[,2]` will drop the list attribute:

You are looking for:

```
paste(df[,2][,1],intToUtf8(177),df[,2][,2])
```

Comment: How do I retain the first column as such? For instance, the first row of the desired output is `1 A 76.088250 ± 3.233297`

Comment: just do `cbind(df[1],paste(df[,2][,1],intToUtf8(177),df[,2][,2]))`